# Migrate from GossipingPropertyFileSnitch to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch

Tags: cassandra

I want to migrate my snitch from GossipingPropertyFileSnitch to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch but my datacenter name is datacenter1 name but in Ec2MultiRegionSnitch it is region name. Is it possible to switch in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the snitch from GossipingPropertyFileSnitch to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch, in your case the data center name is changed, which is considered as a **topology change** and impacts the replication strategy of your existing keyspaces. So you need to change the keyspace replication factor accordingly.

Follow the steps provided in the Cassandra docs for **switching snitch** and **topology change**:

http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_switch_snitch.html